# Android Workmanager: Wait for BroadcastReceiver before returning Result

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I am sending SMS using `SmsManager` and I made use of `WorkManager` to be able to do it in background. Since the number of messages is dynamic, I chained `WorkerRequest`'s for this. This is the snippet:

```
private fun startSmsWork(sms: Array<SmsEntity>) {
    val gson = Gson()

    val smsWorkerRequestBuilder = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SmsWorker>()
      smsWorkerRequestBuilder.setInputData(workDataOf(SMS_WORKER_INPUT_KEY to gson.toJson(sms[0])))

    var continuation = WorkManager.getInstance()
      .beginWith(smsWorkerRequestBuilder.build())

    for (i in 1 until sms.size) {
      smsWorkerRequestBuilder.setInputData(workDataOf(SMS_WORKER_INPUT_KEY to gson.toJson(sms[i])))
      continuation = continuation.then(smsWorkerRequestBuilder.build())
    }

    continuation.enqueue()
}
```

And this is my worker class:

```
class SmsWorker(ctx: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, workerParams) {

  override fun doWork(): Result {
    return try {
      val data = inputData.getString(SMS_WORKER_INPUT_KEY)
      val messages = Gson().fromJson(data, SmsEntity::class.java)
      sendSms(messages)
      Result.success()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.e("Sms", e.localizedMessage)
      Result.failure()
    }
  }

  private fun sendSms(msg: SmsEntity) {
    try {
      Log.d("SmsWorker", "Sending message ${msg.id}....")
      val sentIntent = Intent(SENT_INTENT_ACTION)
      sentIntent.putExtra(SENT_INTENT_EXTRA, msg.id)
      val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, sentIntent, 0)

      val deliveredIntent = Intent(DELIVERED_INTENT_ACTION)
      deliveredIntent.putExtra(DELIVERED_INTENT_EXTRA, msg.id)
      val deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, sentIntent, 0)

      val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(msg.num, null, msg.message, sentPI, deliveredPI)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.e("Sms", e.localizedMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

It works okay, BUT I want to be able to monitor each message sent. So I added a `BroadcastReceiver` for this but the intent that the `BroadcastReceiver` receives, would only be the latest one (in case of multiple messages). I found out that I have to wait for a message to be sent before sending one.

My question is how would I be able to implement this inside my worker class that it should wait for the result in `BroadcastReceiver` before returning the `Result` object.

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: A bit late to the party, but i've had the same problem with the broadcast receiver receiving multiple times the data of the last message. The solution was to assign the message id to the action field of the pending intent, which forced the OS to treat the different callbacks separately

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait asynchronously for the result of an operation during a worker, use a ListenableWorker.

Also, some general advice: since you're dealing with SMS, I'm pretty sure you will need a network constraint for your work. And you may also want to look at unique work and appending if that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up removing the chain and having a listener for broadcast receiver that will start a unique work. 

Doesn't network constraint refer to wifi or mobile data? I'm not really sure, I plan to run a periodic work every N minutes to check if there are messages need to be resend.

Comment: You probably want a metered network for SMS unless you can send it over WiFi. Specifically, not having any network connection means nothing will get sent.